# Parsing the debugger keyword

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

What are the parsing rules regarding the `debugger` keyword?

On Chrome, the following works fine:

```
debugger
console.log('Hello!')
```

but

```
debugger console.log('Hello!')
```

is a `SyntaxError`.

Why is replacing one form of whitespace (new line) by another form of whitespace (space) so critical? What are the parsing rules for `debugger`?

Comment: The bebugger only works on BeOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not related to the `debugger` statement at all, it's down to [automatic semi-colon insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons).

It's the same as trying

```
alert('Hi');
console.log('Hello');
```

and

```
alert('Hi') console.log('Hello');
```

Automatic semi-colon insertion is turning your input into;

```
debugger;
console.log('Hello!');
```